# SAS - SGPLOT - adding XAXIS group label

Tags: sas

I am looking for an option to add a group label (grouping value of Xaxis). I tried X2AXIS and REFLINE option but none is working exactly. (see attached image for reference - I would like to add G1, G2 and G3 with brackets)

[image]

Comment: What kind of plot ? `SERIES` ? `SCATTER` ? `VBAR` ? Other ?

Comment: it will be vbox

Comment: Add to question, some sample data and code tried.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, consider

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2021);
  do x = 1 to 6;
    do _n_ = 1 to 2+ rand('integer', 5);
      y = 5 + rand('integer', 10);
      group = cats ('G', int((x+1)/2));
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;


ods html file='plot.html';

proc sgplot data=have;
  vbox y / group=group category=x;

run;

ods html close;
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks, There are too many categories on my mock graph (which I need to produce) and it would be more transparent to have a group label. I was hoping that X2AXIS or XAXISTABLE of something else could allow to easily group and put an appropriate label.